# how to work with form based authentication in SharePoint 2010 three tier architecture?

Tags: 2007, forms-authentication, sql-server, architecture

I am working on SharePoint2010 site created on three tier architecture. I want to use the form based authentication method.

I have prepared the form based authentication on web application but getting

> SQL login failed
> **Update (error message getting in ULS)**
> SQL database login for 'SharePoint_Config' on instance 'SERVER' failed. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.  Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\SERVER NAME$'.

I am referring this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kaevans/sql-server-provider-for-claims-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010).
Please help me which steps I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you run SQL Server Profiler on the SQL Server instance enabling Logon events only. Leave it running while trying to logon to SharePoint. It will tell you who is trying to reach the SQL Server. Very likely you SharePoint application pool account.

The section **Granting Access to SQL Server** is where you need to revisit.

> When we created the SharePoint web application, we used the Network Service account for the application pool identity.  This is the account that will actually call into SQL Server for authentication and authorization.  I used Network Service here for a quick example, but you probably are going to use some other service account in a real environment.
>
> Whatever identity you chose for the application pool needs to have access to SQL Server.  Add a login for SQL Server for the account used in the application pool.
> Next, grant permissions to that user by adding them to the appropriate roles.  I added the user to the aspnet_Membership_BasicAccess and  aspnet_Roles_BasicAccess roles.

Comment: SQL profiler is not showing my webapp details. ULS shows the error "SQL login failed", "unable to initialize the timer" etc. I have tried the section "Granting Access to SQL Server" but no luck. after setting up the network service account I was unable to open the login page. I am already using an account which full access on db and on web app.

Comment: Its three tier application with one web server, app server and one db server.